# JavaScript Bug in Async/Await

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a code in javascript which is using promises. The code is as follows:-

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("here");
    }, 15000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {

  let a = ""

  const result1 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  const result2 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  a.concat(result1, result2)
  console.log('calling');
  console.log(a)

}

asyncCall();
console.log("tmkoc")
```

i am not getting that why the output of a is "" because the code is declared as async await so the  function must wait until each call is resolved and then the concatenation happen and then console log must happen.

Comment: `asyncCall();` is not called asynchronously, so it won't be awaited.

Comment: Note: your `resolveAfter2Seconds` actually resolves after 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with `async/await`, it works correctly here.

The problem is that `a.concat` returns a new string, it does not mutate the original one.

To fix your code you would have to reassign `a` variable

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  resolve("here");
  }, 15000);
   });
 }

async function asyncCall() {

  let a  = ""

  const result1 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();   
  const result2 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();  
  a = a.concat(result1,result2) // reassign the variable
  console.log('calling');
  console.log(a) 

}

asyncCall();
console.log("tmkoc")
```

Comment: thanks for answering , i made a silly mistake there

Comment: Don't worry, it happens, sometimes it's not visible at the first look :)